# How can I know what id for each widget if I custom a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Some default widget's layout may not suitable for me, so I use custom layout

For example, I use custom layout for `SwitchPreference`

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="pre_key"
    android:title="this is title"
    android:switchTextOff="　"
    android:switchTextOn="　"
    android:layout="@layout/switch_preference"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
```

This is `switch_preference.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_widget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example, the title is work, it can display correct title

But the Switch is not working, it cannot change and restore the preference value

How can I find the widget ID if I use custom layout?

---

Update question:

I try to use `android:id="@android:id/switch_widget"`, it prompt a message `requires API level 24`, I ignore this message and run the app, the result is not work.

Then I change minSdkVersion to 24, and run the app on other device(7.0), this time everything is work.

But my app need to support to 19, so I change the `Switch` to `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` and try `android:id="@+id/switchWidget"`, then install the app on Android 5.0.1, this time it is not work again.

Is there any id can work before API 24? SwitchPreference should be added in API 14, why the id is not work in 19?

Comment: How are you implementing this in your code? Show some code

Comment: No code, I just replace the xml, not using custom class to extends `SwitchPreference`

Answer (score 0):

the id for the switch is `android:id="@+id/switchWidget"` use that and it will be automatically picked up by android.

```
<!-- Layout used by SwitchPreference for the switch widget style. This is inflated
     inside android.R.layout.preference. -->
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: see this is the layout used by the android.